# How to vectorize/group together many signals generated from Qsys to Altera Quartus

Tags: vectorization, intel-fpga, qsys

In the Altera Qsys, I am using ten input parallel ports (lets name them pio1 to pio10), each port is 12 bits. These parallel ports obtain values from the vhdl block in Quartus schematic. In the schematic bdf, I can see pio1 to pio10 from the nios ii system symbol so I can connect these pios to other blocks in my bdf.

My question is, how to vectorize these pio1 to pio10? Instead of seeing all ten pios one line by one line coming out from the Nios system symbol, what should I do in order to group all these ten pios so that I only see one instead of ten? From the one pio that I see, I can name it pio[1..10][1..12], the first bracket means pio1 to pio10, the second bracket means bit1 to bit 12 because each parallel port has 12 bits.

Could you please let me know how could I do that?